# Failing to select or set focus to a custom control

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code to select a custom control. But it does not want to set the active control to 'uPnlEntryOptions'. I have tried using control.select as well, same result.  I have also tried 
ActiveControl = uPnlEntryOptions

Code

```
uPnlEntryOptions.Visible = True     
uPnlEntryOptions.Refresh()
uPnlEntryOptions.Select()
uPnlEntryOptions.Focus()
Debug.Print(CStr(uPnlEntryOptions.Focused))
Debug.Print(CStr(uPnlEntryOptions.CanFocus))
```

Output

> False
>
> True

Comment: Using ActiveControl = uPnlEntryOptions prints the active control name as something else as well

Comment: What is the type of uPnlEntryOptions - if custom what does it inherit from?  Does it contain sub-controls?  I presume it has Enabled = true?

Comment: Yes enabled is true. It only contains buttons. Sorry, not sure what you mean by what does it inherent from?

Comment: Its a User Control

Comment: What is the value of uPnlEntryOptions.ContainsFocus at the end?

Comment: Just tested, it is 'True'

Comment: Why would ContainsFocus = True, when Focused = 'False'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Focused property is true only if the control has the focus, not a sub-control.

Calling Select (or Focus?) on a UserControl will select the first child control.  Afterwards the UserControl.ContainsFocus = True since the focus is WITHIN the UserControl, but the UserControl.Focused = False, since the UserControl itself isn't the focused control.